# python input causing checkmarx sql_injection/command_injection

Tags: python, pandas, checkmarx

We have a Flask/ML application which while training takes user input. While in production, it skips taking input from user and reads in from a steps.ob file.

However, Checkmarks still identifies this as a potential SQL injection vulnerability.

```
for i in range(0, n): 
    ele = input("Enter column name (one at a time): ")
    cols_drop.append(ele) # adding the element
X = df.drop(cols_drop,axis='columns')
```

Is there any short workaround for clearing this vulnerability? (In production, since we are supplying the steps.ob file, it won't take user input but checkmarx is not considering that there is an if/else production condition)

Comment: Can you share your SQL query? It will help to guide you.

Comment: the "sql" query is "X = df.drop(cols_drop,axis='columns')". It's a drop command on a dataframe and checkmarx tags it

Answer (score 0):

Static analysis doesn't execute your code with values to see which logic branches are taken.  In Checkmarx' case, it is doing data flow analysis so will ignore `if/else` and see the flow from the user-interactive `input` to your DB API.  This means this is a true-positive result. You just have to decide if it is exploitable or not due to (perhaps) compensating controls in place during deployment.

Given that SQL Injection is reported, it is likely that your code isn't doing proper SQL parameter binding/sanitization OR Checkmarx doesn't recognize the API you're using for SQL I/O.  There is not enough code to really tell if this is the case, I am making some assumptions based on the content of your question.

I am also fairly certain Checkmarx doesn't recognize any of the Pandas API to understand that it is also subject to an interactive input via the `steps.obs` file.  Depending on how that file gets placed and is secured from potential modifications by an attacker, that may be a false-negative SQL injection.  If the Pandas API were recognized, the analysis would potentially see the file input and give you another SQL Injection vulnerability.

The good news is both would be resolved with proper parameter binding.  If you are already doing proper parameter binding, you have some choices:

1. Mark it as Not Exploitable
2. Tune the analysis queries to recognize any sources/sinks/sanitizers

Checkmarx can usually help you tune the query.